# Implement search functionality with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, search

I have three tables

1. `SalesDetails` with columns SalesId, ProductId, Qty, Price etc
2. `SalesPersonDtls` with columns SalesId, SalesPersonId, CommPercentage etc
3. `SalesPerson` with columns SalesPersonId, firstName, lastName etc

I have second table because one sale can be done by more than one sales person together with split commission.

I have various inputs in search screen like productname, sales date, sales person name etc.

I am making the model class as 'AsQueryable' and add various where conditions and finally the result into a list.

I have sales person's name in search criteria but I don't know how to include this into the search. Can you please help?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: First, I would copy your actual models as code snippets instead of a hard to read paragraph. Then show your current query. Taking a blind shot and assuming you have navigation properties defined, I would say your probably looking for something like `var matches = context.SalesDetails.Select(** Project Your Needed Data Here **).Where(sd => sd.SalesPersons.Any(sp => sp.lastName == "Jones" && sp.firstName == "Peter").ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

Peter

If I get it correct , relation of your business models is like this :

person (n) <-----> (1) Sale (1) <-----> (n) Details

you put sale and person relation in "SalesPersonDtls" and sale and detail relation to "SalesDetails". I think it's better to change your entities a little bit, if you want to get better result as your project getting bigger and more complex.

Your entities should be like this :

```
    Sale
    {
        List<SalesDetail> details;
        List<Person> persons;
        ...
    }
    SalesDetail
    {
       Sale
       ...
    }
    Person
    {
       Sale
       name
       ...
    }
```

Now it's really simple , if you want sales that is related to a personName :

```
sales.Where(sale => sale.Persons.Any(person => person.PersonName == "your input name"));
```

UPDATE :
If you can't or don't want to change your models:
first you need to find personId by it'name and then search into your "SalesPersonDtls" and get saleIds.